# How do I print a specific value in one column based on the value in another using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel data in column B (cells B2:B60) that contains email addresses (such as `xxx@ahcptcare.com`). In column D, I need to print "APC" if the value in B contains `ahcptcare.com`, or `UDP` if the value in B contains `@upschyd.com`, and so on for more email addresses.

I don't know how to look for the text after the `@` symbol in column B and return another value in column D. I started researching on RIGHT and FIND functions in VBA but I'm at loss on this one. I think I can use and IFS and RIGHT but I'm not sure how to.
How can I do this?

Comment: `Split(cell.Value, "@")(1)` would be the part of the value after "@" (assuming all cells have a single "@")

Comment: So you need to check if "in string" there is an @ sign.  Then if there is you need to "Split" the text and put the contents after the @ sign in a cell that is "offset" by 2 columns.  I would start by googling the words in quotes. IE Google VBA Split, VBA in string, VBA offset. -  The reason: You will learn nothing if someone does it for you.

Comment: Here's a good start. Work with this and show us how far you get: you can either use `Mid() and InStr()` to look for the "@" in your string (cell.value) -OR- use `Split()` to turn the `cell.value` into an array. If you only have one address in each cell I would start with `Mid() and InStr()` as I think it's a more forgiving method for new users.           Avoid looking at all the cells at once, start by writing a script that can pull out just one cell's domain name. Last tip, use debug.print to show you what's happening throughout your code. ( I assume you already know how to do this in excel?)

Answer (score 0):

I'll go over how this would work for the following example data in Excel and hopefully it will teach you how to apply similar VBA code to your own Excel data. It's been a while since I've written VBA, so there may be more efficient ways to do this.

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Email |  | Result |
|  | john1@abc.com |  |  |
|  | john2@xyx.com |  |  |
|  | john3@qrf.com |  |  |
|  | john4@wtf.com |  |  |
|  | john5@omg.com |  |  |
|  | john6@bbq.com |  |  |

First you need to determine your business logic: what is it you are trying to do? Well, you have a range of data that you want to loop over, and, based on part of the data, print a specific string/value to another column in the same row as each data point, respectively.

In my case, I have data in cells B2:B7 of column B (Email), and I want to print a value to column D (Result).

The first thing we need to do in VBA is declare some variables for the data we are going to work with:

```vb
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range 'We are running through a range of cells, so the datatype of Range is appropriate here
Dim cellVal As Variant, comparisonVal As Variant 'Each cell will have text and special characters, so I just used the catch-all datatype of Variant here
Set rng = Range("B2:B7") 'This is just my range of data
```

Now that we've got some variables declared, you can start on your loop now. You need to loop through each cell in your range, so that's first... and there's not much better for looping through a set range of cells than a `for each ... in` loop in VBA.

I typically write the entire loop 'wrapper' first and then click inside it to start writing what will happen for each iteration.

```vb
For Each cell In rng

Next cell
```

Next, we'll jump inside that loop and write the steps we want to loop through. After you move to be inside the loop, we need to determine the value of the cell (but only the part after the @ symbol) and store that value so that it can be compared against later. It's also good practice to check whether there is an @ symbol in the first place... otherwise your code may go off the rails.

```vb
cellVal = cell.Value 'We're assigning this here rather than in the original variable declaration section because its value needs to change with each cell we loop through
If InStr(1, cellVal, "@") > 0 Then 'The InStr() function checks whether a specified value exists in a string
    comparisonVal = Split(cellVal, "@")(1) 'Here we assign the value we want to use for comparison by using the Split() function to give us the value after the @ symbol. Note that this may not work if the @ symbol appears multiple times in a cell in column B. Lookup the Split() function for further information.
Else
    MgBox ("No @ symbol found! Exiting loop.") 'If we don't find an @ symbol in one of the rows, we should probably alert the user. Dirty source data plagues even the best of us.
End If
```

OK! We're almost there. Now we just need to... actually apply the right Result value in column D based on the value in our `comparisonVal` variable. I don't know the extent of your data or business logic, but from what you've shared in your question, it sounds like you have some predetermined Result values to put into the Result column depending on the value of the Email column (column B).

When you have several predetermined routes you want to follow based on several possible scenarios, the best way to achieve that is often a switch statement (sometimes called a case statement). The syntax for that in VBA is:

```vb
Select Case [comparison]
Case [case value 1]
Case [case value 2]
...
Case Else
End Select
```

In our case (no pun intended...), we'll use `comparisonVal` (which contains just the part of each email address after the @ symbol) and assign the appropriate value to column D of the current row. To do that assignment in a relative way, we'll use the `Offset()` function; you can look that up later for further reading if necessary. Remember, this bit of code also goes inside the foreach loop.

```vb
Select Case comparisonVal
Case "abc.com"
    cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "APC"
Case "xyz.com"
    cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "UDP"
Case "qrf.com"
    cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "THC"
Case "wtf.com"
    cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "IDK"
Case "omg.com"
    cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "LOL"
Case Else
    cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Unknown Value"
End Select
```

Run all of that code inside your subroutine or function and you'll end up with the following data result (when you start with the data in the table above):

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Email |  | Result |
|  | john1@abc.com |  | APC |
|  | john2@xyx.com |  | UDP |
|  | john3@qrf.com |  | THC |
|  | john4@wtf.com |  | IDK |
|  | john5@omg.com |  | LOL |
|  | john6@bbq.com |  | Unknown Value |

Which should get you to 100% task completion!

Comment: I'm getting an error: object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: @Chell_80 Please update your question with the full code you've written so far and specify the line that the error occurs on (if you don't know how to do that, try using the F8 key on your keyboard to step through the VBA code, line by line, rather than running it all at once. Alternatively, just press Alt+F11 to open the module in the VBA Editor and run it from there; it should stop on the line that throws the error).

Comment: Sub training()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim cellVal As Variant, comparisonVal As Variant
Set rng = Range("B2:B60")

For Each cell In rng

Next cell

cellVal = cell.Value

If InStr(1, cellVal, "@") > 0 Then
    comparisonVal = Split(cellVal, "@")(1)
Else
    MsgBox ("No @ symbol found! Exiting loop.")
End If

Comment: The yellow arrow is pointing to cellVal = cell.Vaule and the error is: Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: @Chell_80 It looks like you did not read the answer correctly; the if statement goes inside the loop, not after it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a loop and two lines of code.   If you are just checking for those 2 domains then

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Sheets(1).Range("B2:B60")
Dim c As Range
'Loop through each cell in the range
For Each c In r
    'Check for the first domain then check for the second.
    If InStr(1, UCase(c.Value), "AHCPTCARE.COM", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then c.Offset(0, 2).Value = "APC"
    If InStr(1, UCase(c.Value), "UPSCHYD.COM", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then c.Offset(0, 2).Value = "UDP"
Next
```

Comment: This is 9 lines of code, not 2. This also doesn't take into consideration whether there are other cases (see OP's remark in the question "*and so on for more email addresses*", nor does the LoC comment acknowledge that (honestly that's just noise and for such a simple operation, # of LoC are irrelevant. Once you add in more considerations, this is basically the same as my solution, just using `if` statements rather than a `switch` statement, which is not as good logically for a series of possible outcomes (`if` statements make more sense when there are basically only 2 outcomes, sometimes 3).

Comment: Even if there were only two possible outcomes (as demonstrated in this answer), an if-else would have been better than two separate if statements, in terms of logic and readability.